# Marketing Cloud - Timezone - Format/Display

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, timezone, formatting

I guys. Need your help, please.

1 -I know the dates in Marketing are saved in CST timezone, but when I view them in "form mode" I need to see them as GMT / UCT. I have already set up account and user preferences, but the time with the CST format still appears.

2 - I need to do a query to see if the date is within X days of reaching the limit, and this is returning the wrong records because the timezone from GMT to CST "lost 1 day."

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1: You may want to set the submission date as follows:

> SET @submission_date =
>   Format(SystemDateToLocalDate(NOW()),"yyyy-MM-dd")

2: Once the date is right when you create the filter using local time zone setting check box(Account Time Zone), in this way you will get the right result sets.

Thanks